# how to get array elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi i have an array something like below

```
test = [{"text":"value1","weight":20,"link":"javascript:myink('Val','val')"}]
```

I want the text value in the above array that is 'value1'. I have tried like this,

```
var getval= JSON.stringify(test);
```

But i failed. Please help me

Comment: if you know it's an array, access it like an array; your code is stringifying the entire `test` array instead of using specifically the first entry in that array, so either you simply forgot to use a [0], which is possible, or you don't quite understand arrays yet, in which case it's a good idea to read up on how to work with arrays in JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to read `value` from that array you would use

```
var x = test[0].text
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with stringify, but to get the value for 'text' in the first element using the array you have declared :

```
test[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = [{"text":"value1","weight":20,"link":"javascript:myink('Val','val')"}]

console.log(test[0].text);
```

There is an array test that has an object at [0] index. This object has several properties one of which is "text". So to access the object we do `test[0]` and to access the property we `do test[0]`. That is the complete explanation to your scenario.